# why in api 28 the app is not really killed when "Background process limit - No background processes" is checked

Tags: android, kill-process

with android os 7.1.1 when "Background process limit - No background processes" is checked (in developer option settings),  when minimized the app and re-open the app, all global data like `val ViewModelDataMap = HashMap<String, Data>(), which is defined in file level - not inside any class`  are destroyed.

(also has the `dont keep activity alive` setting on)

but with api 28,  when re-open the app the map is still have the old data in the map, seems the app has not been destroyed (although the trace shows the activity/fragment's onDestroy() are called).

why the behaviors are different? does with the api 28 that the os will not destroy the app process even if chosen `"Background process limit - No background processes"`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, I'd have complete answer. However, the reason about Background processes is changed, because of the new configuration of `LMKD` starting with Pie Android 28. There is a lot of changes, but in [the documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/lmkd#using_userspace_lmkd), there are few words only about this.

Regarding **Don't keep Activities**. It should work in any version, because it's completely different thing and not driven by `process` term here. It's another simpl optimization, for clearing `Activities` in background (where process might be still alive).